# Adding text after each while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

This is my code

```
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    echo "Title: $data[1]<BR>";
    echo "Time: $data[2]<BR>";
}
echo 'Results End. <hr>';
}
```

I want the horizontal line to appear after each result however it just appears after the last one. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: put the `echo "results end <hr>"` inside the loop before the first `}` or just the `hr` instead of `br` if that's what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `echo "Results End.<hr>"` in `while loop`.

```
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

echo "Title: $data[1]<BR>";
echo "Time: $data[2]<BR>";
echo "Results End.<hr>";
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixes the <hr> but I need Results End after every results this just prints it at the end.

Comment: Look i have modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put a line after each result :)

```
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Title: $data[1]<br/>";
        echo "Time: $data[2]<hr/>";
    }
    echo 'Results End.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the `<hr>` tag inside the while loop to have it with each result. `<br>` is a newline, `<hr>` is the horizontal line